# Why won't my Sub activate the sheet I want?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub that fills a data sheet with data, and then I want it to activate a results sheet. However, no matter how I try, when the Sub is completed, it always displays the data sheet instead of the results sheet.

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click()

Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("DataEntry")

LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = TextBox1.Text 
LastRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = TextBox13.Text 

Worksheets("DataEntry").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("O1").Value = TextBox1.Text

Worksheets("ResultSplash").Activate 'I've tried activating it
Call ResultSplash 'I've tried calling a sub that activates it


    Unload Me
End Sub
```

I've tried a couple other things too, but cannot get the ResultSplash sheet to display!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try activating a cell in that sheet.

Comment: The question is, why do you even need to `Activate` anything?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I do that in my code sometimes when I want a landing page displayed for end user.

Comment: I ran your code............it worked perfectly............make sure there is nothing "special" about the `DataEntry` worksheet like protected or hidden.

Comment: Tried selecting a cell in a sheet with that sheet, still didn't work. I don't have any protected or hidden sheets. STILL will open DataEntry instead of ResultSplash when done :(

Comment: `Worksheets("ResultSplash").Activate | range("a1").select` still fails?

Comment: Yup: https://gyazo.com/1c8517f709ca387b44a53f759c493493
Still opens "DataEntry" instead of "ResultSplash" when it's done.

Comment: Someone mentioned ScreenUpdating.  ScreenUpdating definitely seems like the issue, because sometimes when I run the sub, I'm also unable to make (or see) changes to the DataEntry sheet. I don't see .ScreenUpdating anywhere in my code though

Comment: This is all one workbook right? If so, please consider throwing garlic and setting your computer on fire. It's possessed XD

Comment: Can you activate `ResultsSplash` manually **??**

Comment: Yes, I can activate ResultsSplash manually.  I added a "Wait" function to the "btnCalc_Click", now I can SEE the ResultSplash being activated, but when the "Unload Me" function runs, it reverts back to the "DataEntry" page.

Comment: It seems the "Unload Me" function is what's causing it to revert back to DataEntry

Comment: so try shifting `Unload` statement somewhere else (as it shoud be...). For instance substitute it with `Me.Hide` in your `Sub btnCalc_Click()` and add `Unload MyUserForm` (change "MyUserForm" with your UserForm actual name) statement in the sub where you placed `MyUserForm.Show` , right after the last UserForm block statement

Comment: Now as soon as the application is hidden, the sheet still goes back to "DataEntry"

Comment: So I explicitly made all my userforms vbModeless (even though I thought this was the default, and I didn't set anything to Modal), and now it works!

Comment: I make the echo of my last comment in my answer since I'd like to read possible feedbacks from people here: 
 
"this means that any call to the Activate method was blocked by some userform (other than the one with Sub btnCalc_Click()) popped out before and still waiting to be closed. If that "pending" userform is relevant for acquiring and/or processing data than you should leave it Modal and take care of properly closing it. Modeless userforms are, as to my experience, to be left for some "informative" forms to be shown and kept updated while real processing is taking place"

Answer (score 4):

you shouldn't even activate "DataEntry"

just substitute this code

```
Worksheets("DataEntry").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("O1").Value = TextBox1.Text
```

with this

```
ws.Range("O1").Value = TextBox1.Text
```

Comment: Upvoted but it's unclear where the button click takes place so this may not suffice.

Comment: ditto for me @findwindow - I am not 100% sure, but I suspect moving `Worksheets("ResultSplash").Activate` after `Unload Me` may help.

Comment: @findwindow true. but shouldn't this suffice at least Jules has a way to go: activate "DataEntry" at the beginning and never loose it using fully qualified references

Comment: @ScottHoltzman there MUST be the way since ... _"There's always a way out"_

Comment: **This does not address the question**.  The issue is not the best way to set a cell in `DataEntry`.  The issue is why `Activation` fails..............still the answer is valuable and I will not down-vote it.

Comment: The button click takes place on a different page, then the data is entered onto "DataEntry".  I substituted the code as suggested above, but when the Sub is finished, it still opens "DataEntry" instead of "ResultSplash".  I also tried moving the activate to after the Unload Me. Didn't work.  I also tried selecting a cell within "ResultSplash", still didn't work.

Comment: has been issued an `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` statement anywhere before during code execution?

Comment: ^ ScreenUpdating definitely seems like the issue, because sometimes when I run the sub, I'm also unable to make (or see) changes to the DataEntry sheet. I don't see .ScreenUpdating anywhere in my code though

Comment: As the last (for me) chance: it could have been issued once during Excel session and never restored back to `True`. Try typing in the Immediate Window `?Application.ScreenUpdating` and press return

Comment: ?Application.ScreenUpdating showed "True" when I clicked enter.

Comment: @JulesHill - is there any workbook or worksheet event code that may be causing this to happen?

Comment: `Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = True
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
Application.CommandBars("Full Screen").Enabled = False
End Sub
` 
This is in "ThisWorkbook", there is no code on any sheet. I added a "Wait" function, and I can see that the "ResultSplash" is being displayed, but when the "Unload Me" function runs, the DataEntry page is displayed again.

Comment: So I did some testing, and whenever this specific UserForm closes, it opens the DataEntry sheet for some reason

Comment: is there any `UserForm_Terminate()` or `UserForm_Deactivate()` event handler in UserForm code pane?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I have never used those, so I don't think they're in any of my code.

Comment: well, just look in you userform code pane. or type "Terminate" (and then "Deactivate") in the Find (CTRL +F) utility selecting "Current project" radiobox

Comment: _"whenever this specific UserForm closes, it opens the DataEntry sheet "_ have you actually tried substituting this specific Userform with another (possibly brand new) one doing the same things?

Comment: So I explicitly made all my userforms vbModeless (even though I thought this was the default, and I didn't set anything to Modal), and now it works!

Comment: this means that any call to the `Activate` method was blocked by some userform (other than the one with `Sub btnCalc_Click()`) popped out before and still waiting to be closed. If that "pending" userform is relevant for acquiring and/or processing data than you should leave it _Modal_ and take care of properly closing it. _Modeless_ userforms are, as to my experience, to be left for some "informative" forms to be shown and kept updated while _real_ processing is taking place.